What are these cylinders with holes for in a universal PCB enclosure?
The rubbery screws act like legs on the other side of the enclosure. What are the cylinders with holes for? The metal screws that came with the enclosure don't fit them.

What are these screws for if they can't be put in any hole?

Update: I realized you put the metal screws under the rubbery screws that act as legs. I still don't know what the four cylinders with hole in the center are for, though.

Presumably there is a lid? Can you include the screws and lid in the photo?... I'd guess that the included screws are to fix the lid on, and the "rubbery screws" are feet to go over the screws.

@Attie Oh, you're right! Thanks. But when what are those four cylinders with holes in the middle for?

I can't quite tell from the pictures in terms of the dimensions, but the screws might be Thread Forming Screws for Plastic

Those lower bosses are for mounting your circuit board inside the enclosure. You may have to supply your own screws for that. The raised ones are for mounting the lid. Those screws usually come supplied with the enclosure.

Scaling off the stripboard hole pitch, the screw holes in those bosses are unusually large.  Counting pixels they come out to about 3.5mm, and that's the minor diameter of the screw, so M4 if metric (well, they're probably not tapped, so not really a machine screw).  M3 is the biggest I'd expect to be used for small boards (and even PC motherboards).

@ChrisH The mold might have been designed for M3 threaded inserts, but the manufacturer cheaped out and didn't install them :)

@jpa that wouldn't surprise me

@ChrisH You wouldn't use machined screws - the threads are too fine. You would use wood, plastic or even sheet metal screws over machined screws.

@MOSFET, as I said, not really a machine screw, but that gives us a guide to the diameter.  You'd still need something with a core diameter of >~3.5mm, plus thread, and the thread on a self-tapping screw sticks out further.  You'd end up with something like 5mm holes through your board.  And that sort of plastic can take a machine screw thread.  The reason that's not done is mainly cost
